# updating my project from xamarin forms to maui MasterDetailPage not found

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maui

I am updating my xamarin forms to maui and ran the upgrade assistant tool. I an getting some errors about the MasterDetailPage  not being found. Is there a different way for me to do this in `maui`

error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MasterDetailPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Code

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    try
    {
        var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
        masterDetailPage.Detail = new BaseNavigationPage(new HomePage());
        masterDetailPage.IsPresented = false;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be noted that the [MasterDetailPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage?view=xamarin-forms) is obsolete as of version 5.0.0 and has been removed obsolete usage on Maui.Controls, see:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/1644.

However, in MAUI, you can use [FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/flyoutpage) instead as an alternative solution.

Comment: So I need to convert my page to use the Shell?

Comment: Yes, you can use the [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/?view=net-maui-8.0). Also, [FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.flyoutpage) is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps, and an exception will be thrown if you attempt to use [FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.flyoutpage) in a Shell app. For more information about Shell apps, see [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/?view=net-maui-8.0).